# Joomla taks works with Friendly url OFF but do not with Friendly url ON

Tags: joomla, friendly-url, joomla-task

I have trouble with joomla 3.3.3 site. When my Firendly url is off this url with task works fine

```
<a href="<?php echo Juri::root(); ?>index.php?option=com_ezwatchlists&amp;task=delete&amp;rowid=<?php echo $row->id; ?>"><?php echo JText::_('EZWATCHLISTS_DELETE')?></a>
```

but when i turn ON Friendly url task is ignored.

NOTICE: When I look in file inspector I see link like this:

```
<a href="http://www.example.com/index.php?option=com_ezwatchlists&amp;task=delete&amp;rowid=30"></a>
```

and when copy paste that link then task works fine.

Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With Joomla, you should use the JRoue class which will take care of all your URLs for you, whether you have SEF enabled or disabled. So change you code to the following:

```
<a href="<?php echo JRoute::_('index.php?option=com_ezwatchlists&task=delete&rowid=' . $row->id); ?>">
    <?php echo JText::_('EZWATCHLISTS_DELETE'); ?>
</a>
```

For more information, have a read of the following:

https://docs.joomla.org/Supporting_SEF_URLs_in_your_component

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for replay.
This link also works when I copy to url bar but do not work when i click on it.